# Google-maps API fusion table and styled map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

ive been trying to get an fusiontable overlay to work with a styled google map for this website i am making, currently i have the overlay working on one map, but as soon as i style is the overlay doesnt want to apply, ihavent been able to find an info on this anywhere ferom my searches, so if anyone can help thatll be great, hear is my script for the map with the overlay

```js
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 3,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });
 var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'geometry',
     from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk'
      },
      map: map,
      suppressInfoWindows: true
});
    }
```

and here is the code with the styled map but the overlay not working:

```js
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        var styles = [
          {
              "featureType": "administrative",
              "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
              "stylers": [ { "color": "#444444"  } ]
          },
          {
              "featureType": "landscape",
              "elementType": "all",
              "stylers": [{"color": "#FF00FF"}]
          },
          {
              "featureType": "poi",
              "elementType": "all",
              "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]
          },
          {
              "featureType": "road",
              "elementType": "all",
              "stylers": [{"saturation": -100
                  },
                  {"lightness": 45}]
          },
            {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{"visibility": "simplified"}]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                "elementType": "labels.icon",
                "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{"visibility": "off"}]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [{"color": "#00FF00"
                    },
                    {"visibility": "on"}]
            }
        ];
    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType( styles, {name: "Styled Map"});
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style'] }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
        mapOptions);
        map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
        map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
        map.setOptions({ minZoom: 3, maxZoom: 15 });
    };
    var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        query: {
            select: 'geometry',
        from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk'
    },
        map: styledMap,
        suppressInfoWindows: true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the `map` property of the fusionTablesLayer to `styledMap`, that isn't the `google.maps.Map` object (use `map` instead).

Also, you need to keep the initialization of the `FusionTablesLayer` inside the `initMap` function (for a couple of reasons).

```js
function initMap() {
  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {
    name: "Styled Map"
  });
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
    mapOptions);
  map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
  map.setOptions({
    minZoom: 3,
    maxZoom: 15
  });
  var world_geometry = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'geometry',
      from: '1N2LBk4JHwWpOY4d9fobIn27lfnZ5MDy-NoqqRpk'
    },
    map: map,
    suppressInfoWindows: true
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
var styles = [{
  "featureType": "administrative",
  "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#444444"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "landscape",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#FF00FF"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "poi",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "off"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "saturation": -100
  }, {
    "lightness": 45
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.highway",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "simplified"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.arterial",
  "elementType": "labels.icon",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "off"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "transit",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "off"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "water",
  "elementType": "all",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#00FF00"
  }, {
    "visibility": "on"
  }]
}];
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! i'm not very experienced with this at all, so your help is very appreciated.